# Using vs lambda

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming

Is it equivalent?

```
        public static void Using<T>(this T disposable, Action<T> action)
            where T:IDisposable
        {
            try {
                action(disposable);
            }
            finally {
                disposable.Dispose();
            }
        }

        new SqlConnection("").Using(conn => {

        });

        using(var conn = new SqlConnection("")){

        };
```

in other words, can we replace using keyword with this method?

Comment: You might also want to look at this article: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/11/selectmany-combining-idisposable-and.html by Marc Gravell.

Comment: Honest question: Why would you want to?

Comment: How is that simpler? To my eyes they look almost identical, except that one is more syntactically confusing.

Comment: In principle, you can do that. You could do this for many other C# keywords - `for`, `foreach`, `lock`, or even `while` (taking condition function and body function). Lambdas are really powerful :-)

Answer (score 19):

I don't think this is a particularly good idea, because it would also allow us to write

```
var conn = new SqlConnecction("");
conn.Using(c => /* do something with c */);
conn.Open();
```

This would compile, but when you reach the last line, it will throw an ObjectDisposedException.

In any case, the `using` coding idiom is well-known, so why make it harder for your fellow developers to read your code?

Comment: That can also happen with a "classic" `using` statement: `var conn = ...; using(conn) {...}; conn.Open();`

Comment: I consider this replacement only in theory, as using Occam's razor principle.

Comment: @Heinzi That's why we enforce in our coding standards that the object in a using clause is also defined in the using clause - i.e. `using( IDbConnection con = ... ) { ...}`

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Sometimes that is not possible, e.g. before using block (and resource allocation )needed to access the variable (to create a closure which would be passed to the resource).

Answer (score 10):

I note that your method does not do *everything* that a "using" statement does. For example, it does not introduce a new local variable declaration space in which a variable that holds on to the resource may be declared.

Nor does it allow for multiple disposable resources of the same type to be declared all at one go.

And finally, it does not seem to compose particularly elegantly with itself. One of the nice things about "using" as a statement is that you can say:

```
using(something)
using(someotherthing)
using(somethirdthing)
{
   use all three, they'll all get disposed
}
```

How would that look in your proposal?

```
something.Using(
x=>someotherthing.Using(
y=>somethirdthing.Using(
z=> { use all three } )));
```

A bit gross, frankly.

Answer (score 2):

One limitation: you cannot acces out parameters of the containing method in your lambda.

Answer (score 2):

The `using` statement checks for the `disposable` being `null`. Other than that at runtime you will get mostly the same behaviour (other than the additional [stack frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199895/using-vs-lambda/2199921#2199921), and the delegate call).

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons why I'd rather not use this.

**Compile-Time foolproofing**

```
using (var foo=new Bar())
{
  foo=new Bar();// throws an error at compile time
}
```

**Structs implementing IDisposable**

Structs implementing interfaces are boxed when an interface method is invoked on them.
The using statement is smart enough to recognize when its target is a struct at compile time and forgoes the boxing.

Comment: Technically, the bit about structs is actually a compiler bug. The spec says to do the boxing conversion; the implementation does not do so; it just calls Dispose() directly. This is arguably the "more correct" thing to do anyway; if the disposer mutates the struct, then it probably should be mutating the original, not a boxed copy.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature of future CLR versions then ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Richard said, there is an extra method call between creation of the disposable object and the start of the try. This increases the time frame in which a asynchronous exception can take place, which leads to your disposable object not being disposed. However, this isn't a big issue, because types that implement IDisposable should not acquire their resources in the constructor (SqlConnection aquires its resources during the call to the Open() method).

So while your new way of writing the using statement would work, it makes reading for other developers much harder and could easily be abused in the way Mark Seemann notes.

So can you replace the using keyword with your Using extension method? Yes. Should you do it? No.

Answer (score 0):

It's *almost* **functionally** equivalent, but practically speaking it does not provide any benefit. The semantics of the "traditional" `using` statement are well known and standard. While your approach may behave the same (although there are some differences) it introduces unnecessary overhead and complexity - not only do you have additional method invocations you are replicating code yourself that the compiler will automatically generate.

Answer (score 0):

No.
You are demoting a language keyword [meaning compiler can do somethings around it as pointed out by Florian] to a normal method call.

Although semantically they may be the same, compiler won't know what the method will do.
Compile time checks are better than runtime exceptions, as we all know.